# Increase in 404 errors where "%5C%22" features in google results

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I hope someone here can help me

I have started getting alerts from google about increasing 404's.
every one of these has the string "%5C%22" in the url rather than the ascii character.

This issue comes and goes every few months. It's a wp site, with only premium plugins.

The best/ nearest answer I have found is here:

> It seems that google is looking in code that is not designed for it to
>   look at. Indeed Stack Overflow lists a similar issue
>   [Ajax used for image loading causes 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024422/ajax-used-for-image-loading-causes-404-errors).

But there appears to be no real cause identified.

For example
https://rapidbi.com/swotanalysistemplates/%5C%22/ listed in google - but when I go to the page it says contains this link ( https://rapidbi.com/swotanalysistemplates/ ) there is no such link.
Sometimes the %5c%22 is in the middle as well as at the end of a url. So the theory that its a /\ code in PHP makes sense - but how do we solve this?

Could it be that google is reading the PHP instructions?
Should this be an issue that google coders fix rather than us poor webmasters/
or is there a server side solution to this.
I have 100s of these errors increasingly daily!

Should I just ignore these google reported errors? 
Should I mark them as fixed (they are not, as they never existed in the first place)?
Is there a fix? It's a wp based site, should I be changing the robot text to block something? If so what?
do we know of any plugins that might create this issue?

Thank you in advanced
Mike

Comment: There is no way that Google is reading your PHP code. But if you look at the bottom of https://rapidbi.com/swotanalysistemplates/ you'll see that there's a whole cluster of broken links (starting from "More content from the RapidBI team Blog Home page"); those are the links that Google tries to follow. There are possibly more. If a plugin is "premium" (whatever that means) it doesn't guarantee that it's bug-free (or even good).

Answer (score 0):

First, from Google itself. 404s doesn't affect ranking of your website.

But of course we want to fix this kind of error.

Second, on Google Webmaster Tools you can see where "google" saw / crawled this link. I suggest that you check where google pick this URL and look in your code if there's any code that add /%5C%22/ in the URL.

Comment: Google says that the errors are generated on pages with similar errors - ie there is no page that has this!!